# How to know in real time when a website post a new content?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web, web-scraping

I would like to know if there are a way to see a new website page before it is posted in the home page, but after they posted it on Internet.

I tried with sitemaps, but the problem is that I want to monitor it 24/7, and the sitemps shows historical information, not real time.

For example, suppose this scenario:

BBC created an article around 23:05, but they shared it on its home page around 23:15. Are there a way to obtain the link of the article or title of the article before 23:15?

Comment: If a web site has static pages in discrete files then what you suggest might be possible, if you can identify those files. How you do that on one site won't necessarily be applicable to any other site. Many sites draw their content from one or more databases. Stack Overflow and the BBC are two good examples. Content might be posted to the databases hours before it's published, but you'll have no access to it at all until it is published.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  A file on a website is totally invisible unless some other page links to it.

Comment: Not entirely true. If you know the URL of a file you can access it whether or not any other page links to it. The problem is, of course, knowing the URL.

Comment: Perhaps the word "undiscovverable" is better, but the sentiment is correct.